# How can I inherit from UAnimMontage?

Tags: c++, inheritance, unreal-engine4

I am try to inherit from UAnimMontage. Basically I want create a custom AnimMontage which will has a differently number (with specific names) of sections. These sectios depends of the value of an Enum it will has.
This is for a MeleeCombo system, so, I will have a lot AnimMontage and I do not want to repeat same actions to create these AnimMontages. And the sections names will be used in code, so, I think is better automate this.
And is better for artist too, and for everyone really.
This class will be show in Editor, to edit like the normal AnimMontage.
When I create a C++ class which inherit from UAnimMontage (with Wizard C++), it throws me a lot of dependencies errors like this one:

```
2>CloseCombatAnimMontage.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual float __cdecl UAnimSequenceBase::GetPlayLength(void)" (?GetPlayLength@UAnimSequenceBase@@UEAAMXZ)
```

Any idea how could I do this without changing the Engine code???
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the source code, UAnimMontage and the base class are marked with `MinimalAPI`, meaning that you can inherit from them, but have to provide your own implementation for their methods.

So you either copy-paste the implementation of the methods from the engine code into your own implementation or you modify the engine source code so that all methods are exported for linking, not just the api.

Comment: Oh! I understand... Thanks so much!